# Allocate array in main inside a function which is defined outside of main

Tags: c, pointers, calloc

I'm trying to use calloc on array inside a function but it doesn't work. When trying to debug I found that inside the function the pointer points to the allocated memory but when leaving the function it points to NULL again. Tried all kinds of variations but can't seem to find a solution.

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *rows = NULL, *solvedRows = NULL;
    int **board = NULL, **solvedBoard = NULL;
    allocateMemory(dim, &(*rows), &(*board));
    allocateMemory(dim, &(*solvedRows), &(*solvedBoard));
}

void allocateMemory(int dim, int** rows, int*** board) {
    rows = calloc(dim*dim,sizeof(int));
    board = calloc(dim, sizeof(int*));
    if (rows == NULL || board == NULL) {
        printf("Error: calloc has failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Need help to understand what's wrong and how to fix it.

EDIT

I tried:

```
*rows = calloc(dim*dim,sizeof(int));
*board = calloc(dim, sizeof(int*));
```

Still have same problem.

Also tried:

```
allocateMemory(dim, &rows, &board);
```

for line 4 and (5 the same) and in doesn't compile with the error:
"error: passing argument 2 of 'allocateMemory' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  allocateMemory(dim, &rows, &board);
                      ^"
error: passing argument 3 of 'allocateMemory' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  allocateMemory(dim, &rows, &board);
                             ^

**EDIT**

For anyone who encounters this problem and checks this page, this last try is in fact correct, as Michael answered below. The errors are for a mistake in the corresponding header file, and were fixed when fixing the header file.

Comment: `allocateMemory(dim, &(*rows), &(*board));` this doesn't match the signature of `allocateMemory`, you are passing `(int, int*, int**)` but it expects `(int, int**, int***)`.

Comment: i fixed that problem but it doesn't work added in the EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's focus on your `rows` variable:

`rows` is a pointer, which is a variable holding a memory address.
Now you want alocateMemory to write into `rows` the address of a block of memory, to hold your data. Easy enough:

```
size_d dim = 10;
int* rows = 0;
rows = calloc(1, sizeof(int) * dim);
```

However, if you put this code into a function like

```
void allocateMemory(size_t dim, int* rows) {
    rows = calloc(1, sizeof(int) * dim);
}
```

Now if you call this function like

```
int* actualRows = 0;
allocateMemory(3, actualRows);
```

The *value* of `actualRows` (namely `0`) will be copied into a new variable `rows` which you manipulate in `allocateMemory`. When you write into rows, its value changes, but when `allocateMemory` is left, `rows` will be destroyed. Never will `actualRows` be altered.

What you want is that `allocateMemory` sets the value of `actualRows` o a memory address. To do this, you have to provide `allocateMemory` with the *address* of `actualRows` like

```
allocateMemory(3, &actualRows);
```

`&atualRows` is the memory address of `actualRows` and its type is `int**` (pointer to a pointer to `int`).

Now you have to adapt the signature of `allocateMemory` appropriately:

```
void allocateMemory(size_t dim, int** rows) {
    rows = calloc(1, sizeof(int) * dim);
}
```

And, since rows now is a pointer and you want to change its target, you need to dereference it before assigning it:

```
*rows = calloc(1, sizeof(int) * dim);
```

Yielding all in all:

```
void allocateMemory(size_t dim, int** rows) {
    *rows = calloc(1, sizeof(int) * dim);
}

...
int* actualRows = 0;
allocateMemory(3, &actualRows);
...
```

For your `board`, its the same in principle. Try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void allocateMemory(int dim, int** rows, int*** board) {
    *rows = calloc(dim * dim,sizeof(int));
    *board = calloc(dim, dim * sizeof(int*));

    if (rows == NULL || board == NULL) {
        printf("Error: calloc has failed\n");
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
        (*board)[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(int) * dim);

        if ((*board)[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Error: calloc has failed\n");
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    size_t dim = 10;

    int *rows = NULL;
    int **board = NULL;
    allocateMemory(dim, &rows, &board);

    rows[0] = 10;
    rows[1] = 11;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
        printf("%i ", rows[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    board[0][0] = 11;
    board[9][0] = 99;
    board[9][9] = 101;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {

        for(size_t k = 0; k < dim; ++k) {

            printf("%i ", board[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) free(board[i]);
    free(board);

    free(rows);
}
```

Comment: Just start trying to fix the `rows` first as I explained above, then go on to fix the `board`. By the way, `board` is meant to be a matrix with `dim` rows` and how many columns? Or how is `board` supposed to look like?

Comment: the line `int* rows = 0;` is re-decleration, you meant something else?

Comment: OK and the board is supposed to be of size dim*dim. still in the last block of code there is that re-declaration, but also can't understand its original purpose

Comment: It doesn't compile :( i added this in the EDIT section at the last part with the compilation error

Comment: Try the current version of the code I provided at the end of my post, can you provide me with the compilation error?

Comment: So, the solution I suggested in the last code block works fine with me - let me know whether you encounter any further problems and whether there is still something unclear with the `board`. Cheers!

Comment: It was a mistake in the header file thanks so much for the help